# SQL with numeric data type in Carto

Tags: sql, plpgsql

I have a Carto database with column "area" where data type is "number" or numeric.

The following SQL query is to select certain rows (cartodb_ids) and update the geometry (geojsons) and area (area_updates) values of these rows

```
var sql2 = "SELECT draw_items_upsert(ARRAY[";
      sql2 += cartodb_ids.join(",");
      sql2 += "],ARRAY[";
      sql2 += geojsons.join(",");
      sql2 += "],"
      sql2 += "ARRAY[";
      sql2 += area_updates.join(",");
      sql2 += "]);";
```

However it produces the following console error :

“error  [ "column "area" is of type double precision but expression is of type text" ] hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.”

I’ve tried using CAST(area_updates.join AS numeric);
with no success

Is it possible to use “::numeric” if so where does it fit into the query?

Answer (score 1):

"draw_items_upsert" is a custom function and as it turns the amendment was required within that function:

```
 CAST('''|| area_updates[i] ||''' AS numeric)
```